# My Angular js directive is not working for append div

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular. so trying to construct my first directive which interact with DOM but not working. please tell me what i miss in code. here is code.

```
<div class="main" ng-app="myApp">
<button data-ng-click="submit()" my-directive>click</button>
</div>

app.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
     return function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.click(function(){
               alert('hello');
               element.parent().find('.main').append('<div>Some text</div>');
           })
      }
})
```

my js fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/2fooy06c/

Comment: Your JS Fiddle link only point to jsfiddle home page not any working demo.

Comment: Sorry that was mistake. i update the link url.

Comment: Please don't use angular like jquery. You can forget the building and updating dom with element etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element.click is not a function. you need to attach event using .bind

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
     return {
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.bind('click',function(){
               alert('hello');
               element.parent().append('<div>Some text</div>');
           })
           }
      }
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2018/

Comment: i am learning angular. so how many property a directive can have like link: type: template: etc ?  share a link from where i can get full idea. thanks

Comment: @Thomas refer ng-book.

Comment: which ng-book would be best for beginner. suggest me.

Comment: check this link. It can help you a bit on directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the 'link' property:

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
     return {
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs){
          element.click(function(){
               alert('hello');
               element.parent().find('.main').append('<div>Some text</div>');
           })
           }
      }
})
```

Comment: i copied your code but not working here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/2fooy06c/1/

Comment: i am learning angular. so how many property a directive can have like link: ?

Comment: issue is with `element.click`. there is no such function. check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code as below and it will work. There is no such function as `click` in element. Please check this documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Also do not forget to include `type` and `link` attribute in your directive. `Type` is used to indicate what kind of directive you are creating. Refer [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for more details

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
 return {
   type: "A",
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

     element.on("click", function() {
       alert('hello');
       element.parent().append('<div>Some text</div>');
     });

   }

 }
});
```

refer to this plnkr example https://plnkr.co/edit/CYyOKzjR1kBR3U0tG3jv?p=preview for more details

Comment: i test the code but nothing happen when click on button. anyone can give me working version in jsfiddle?

Comment: i am learning angular. so how many property a directive can have like link: type: template: etc ?  share a link from where i can get full idea. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind click function.
See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/Lvc0u55v/2025/)

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
return {
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function () {
           alert('hello');
           element.parent().append('<div>Some text</div>');
        });
    }
  };
});
```